# Can you set Jackon's Include.NON_NULL globally in JAX-RS?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, cxf

I have a JAX-RS API using Apache CXF. Recently I switched from Jettison to Jackson (2.7.1) for JSON handling. I am using JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.

One thing I need to do to help with transition is to ensure that null fields in JSON are not being rendered. For that I am using following annotation on class level:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Book {
 ...
}
```

Is there any way to set it globally, so that I do not have to apply this annotation to every class?

With Jettison I was able to specify properties in beans.xml file, is there a similar approach possible with Jackson to achieve NON_NULL behavior?

```
  <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider">
    <property name="dropRootElement" value="true"/>
    <property name="supportUnwrapped" value="true"/>
  </bean>
```

I have seen some suggestion to set up this property on ObjectMapper level when instantiated, however when using Apache CXF I never create ObjectMapper by hand, as this instantiation is handled by the framework (probably happens somewhere in JacksonJaxbJsonProvider).

Is there any way to set NON_NULL property globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the following configuration as below:

```
<bean id="jacksonJaxbJsonProvider"
    class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="objectMapper"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="objectMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="serializationInclusion" value="NON_NULL"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: That helped me a lot - I got it working by changing constructor-arg line to   <property name="mapper" ref="objectMapper" />. Otherwise it was complaining about converting ObjectMapper to Annotations[] when creating JacksonJaxbJsonProvider. I also needed to move second bean to top-level beans element in beans.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps somebody else, configuring ObjectMapper in beans.xml worked with NON_NULL however my JAXB annotations stopped working. To get both of them working at the same time I resorted to creating my own ObjectMapper provider:

```
@Provider
public class CustomJacksonObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper;

    public CustomJacksonObjectMapperProvider() {
        defaultObjectMapper = createDefaultMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return (defaultObjectMapper);
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(
            AnnotationIntrospector.pair(
                new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector(),
                new JaxbAnnotationIntrospector(mapper.getTypeFactory())
        ));
        return (mapper);
    }
}
```

and registering it in beans.xml (under `jaxrs:providers`) as follows:

```
<bean id="customJacksonObjectMapperProvider" class="CustomJacksonObjectMapperProvider"/>
```